# How to provide SVN username/password to easy_install?

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install Python EGG with `easy_install`, providing a URL of Subversion repository, where sources are hosted:

```
$ easy_install svn://user:secret@svn.example.com/repo/trunk/my-egg
Authentication realm: <svn://svn.example.com:3690> repo
Password for 'me':
```

The problem is that the repository is password protected. How can I provide the desired username/password to `easy_install`?

ps. The only way I see so far is to run `svn info --username...` beforehand in order to cache credentials for a current user.. But it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported a bug for Python team: http://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue121